# need clarification on node.next pointer in python linkedlist

Tags: python, linked-list, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I am having trouble understand pass by value property in python. In the following code, `runner` is making a copy of `current`, and `runner.next`is point to the next node of the given linkedlist, while we set `runner.next` to `runner.next.next`, how is this effecting `cur.next.next`? Are `runner.next` and `cur.next` both point to the same address? Because in my mind, runner is just a copy of current, and it won't have access to the original cur.next. Please lecture me.

```
        def remove_dups_followup(ll):
            if ll.head is None:
                return

            current = ll.head
            while current:
                runner = current
                while runner.next:
                    if runner.next.value == current.value:
                        runner.next = runner.next.next
                    else:
                        runner = runner.next
                current = current.next

            return ll.head
```

Answer (score 0):

```
runner = current
```

This does not create a *copy* of `current`, but rather assigns another name to the object also known as `current`. So `runner` and `current` are simply two different names for the same object instance. Any changes to the state of `runner` therefore also affect `current`, at least until `runner` is reassigned to the next node in the list.